# Visual Studio Code extension with file system provider terminates for unknown reason

Tags: typescript, debugging, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm in the process of writing a Visual Studio Code extension for editing a remote directory which is accessed via a file system provider that in turn utilizes a WebSocket based connection to query the file system properties (similar to this sample, but involving a WebSocket: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/main/fsprovider-sample).

Now everything works in principle until at some point I do receive this error message:

```
Lintings failed on open
File: scriptfs:/user/my_script.py
Message: TypeError: Cannot read property 'uri' of undefined
```

My problem is that I have no idea anymore how to find the origin of this message. Grepping various repos failed, the debugger does not provide a backtrace, the source code links are ending in java script logging code compiled from type script and I have already used huge amounts of 'console.log ()' outputs. I suspect that I did not understand the promise based mechanism correctly and that I'am missing some exception here. A typical file system provider function looks like this:

```
export class ScriptFS implements vscode.FileSystemProvider {
 ...
 readFile (uri: vscode.Uri): Promise<Uint8Array> {

    return new Promise<Uint8Array> ((resolve, reject) => {

      try {
        Connection.instance.send ('scriptfs::read_file', { 'uri': uri.toString () }).then ((reply: any) => {
            if ('error' in reply)
              reject (vscode.FileSystemError.FileNotFound (reply.error));
            else {
              let enc = new TextEncoder ();
              resolve (enc.encode (reply.code))
            }
          }
        ).catch (err => { reject (new Error (err)); });
      }
      catch (e) { reject (new Error (e)); }
    });
  }
  ...
}
```

So my question is:

- Does this provider based pattern here makes sense or did I miss something ?
- Is there a best practice for finding the origin of these 'cannot read property' messages ?

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 0):

After some more investigation, this seems to be a bug the the VSCode python extension, [see github issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/17048). The promised based access above is correct in principle, but the `try/catch` phrase around the inner function body is not necessary, because the `reject/resolve` always applies.